# How to find the element $x\in \mathbb Z_n$ such that $f(x)=1$, where $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $0<m<n$ and $(m,n)=1$. Consider the map $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$ such that $f(1)=m$. Which element $x\in \mathbb Z_n$ has the property that $f(x)=1$?

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> Let us denote the class of $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{n}$ by $[x]$. So you have $f([1]) = [m]$, so that $f([x]) = f([1] x) = [m] x = [m x]$. You are looking for $x$ such that $f([x]) = [mx] = [1]$.

**Hint 2**

> This means $mx \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, so that there is $y \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $m x = 1 + n y$ or $mx - n y = 1$.

**Hint 3**

> Now recall Euclid's algorithm and [Bézout's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: I think, the main thing, one needs to understand here, is how the elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$ look like.